# HTML Language to highlight letters on a website

Tags: html

Is it better to use `strong` or `h1` to `h6` to bring out the letters on a website?  I have seen `strong` but was taught to use `h1` through `h6`.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The `<strong>` tag is a phrase tag. It defines **important text**.

```
<strong>Strong text</strong>
```

The six different HTML headings are usually applied on **titles with different levels**.

```
<h1>This is heading 1</h1>
<h2>This is heading 2</h2>
<h3>This is heading 3</h3>
<h4>This is heading 4</h4>
<h5>This is heading 5</h5>
<h6>This is heading 6</h6>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Strong` just make the text bold while `h1` `h2`...`hn`tags are normally used to point specific parts of your website and their importance.

Is like: H1 is the title, h2 a subtitle, h3 a sub-subtitle.

H3 is inside H2, H2 is inside H1.

Also `strong` is an inline element, while H tags are block elements.

If your text doesn't have a special meaning, `strong` is the best option

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [strong definition on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong), you 'll understand that the strong is for emphasis and you can use it into `p` but `h1` is used for titles and you can use it only once into a page but you can use `strong` as times as you want.